# Compile Asp.NET to 32 bit on 64 bit system

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, 32bit-64bit

I've seen in several places that this can be set in the build options for my project.  However when I go to the Property Pages -> Build for my project, it does not have an option for target platform.  When I go to my solution, most projects have x86 as an option, but the web project only has Any CPU.

How do I force the web page to build to 32 bit?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  Does the drop down not contain the values `x86` and `x64`?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build -> Configuration Manager, select the drop down in the platform column, select new, select x86.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, that option does not exist.  The only option existing in Configuration Manager is Any CPU.

Comment: This is in VS2010, there should be a new and edit option in the dropdown, when you select new you can then add x86 to the list of available platforms.

Comment: Salient point, this is 2008, which i forgot to mention.  However I *do* have add/edit for every project except for the web project.

Comment: Is it a website or web application I suspect it is a website and that is your problem.  If you convert to a web app you will be able to set the target platform.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Solution level NOT Project level and follow the selection / editing suggestions above.

Comment: This should be a comment to the "above" answer you are referencing.  Note that answers do not always appear in the order they were initially submitted.  There are other means of sorting that occur.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this to change was to go in to the .sln file with a text editor and directly hack in the values I needed (which worked).

Comment: I have similar problem.
Can you tell exactly what did you changed in .sln file?
How did you force it to build to 32 bit? Thanks in advance.